# How to suppress some output at Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Once I do a rails c and get some rows form the db like so:

```
users = User.find(:all,:conditions => ["some conds"])
```

then users has say 20 results

If I then do a

```
users.each do |u|
  puts u.name if u.gender == 'male'
end
```

then after printing all the male names, the console again outputs all the content of the users object. I *don't* need to see it again. How can I suppress it? All I am interested in is the output of puts

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's how console works. You enter expression, it prints its value.

```
users.each do |u|
  puts u.name if u.gender == 'male'
end
```

Value of this code is `users` object itself and it is correctly printed. What you print with `puts` is a side effect.

You can still suppress printing full contents of `users` by changing return value of this expression. For example, like this:

```
users.each do |u|
  puts u.name if u.gender == 'male'
end && false
```